# Accessing instance variable with dot sign

Tags: java

I am preparing myself for an OCJP exam. I faced following code:

```
public class Island {
    Island n;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Island i2 = new Island();
        Island i3 = new Island();
        Island i4 = new Island();

        i2.n = i3;
        i3.n = i4;
        i4.n = i2;

    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me what happens here ?

```
i2.n = i3;
i3.n = i4;
i4.n = i2;
```

In details I don't understand what magic stands behind i2.n; i3.n; i4.n
Do I get access to local instance variable through local variable ?

Comment: [Official tutorial on objects and classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html)

Comment: Which part of the expression `i2.n = i3;` don't you understand? Do you know what variables are? Do you know what references are? Do you know what assignment is? Do you know what field access is?

Comment: That's no way to go about things. I want you to clarify what you don't understand. I don't know your level of experience.

Comment: _I do anderstand [...],field access_ `i2.n` is a field access expression.

Comment: You are right with access expression - I admit, however you should pointed me to the correct topic in the object chapter. That's way I still think you contribution to the question was useless. If you didn't want to give precised answer don't type. Advice for future

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each instance of `Island` gets its own version of the `n` field.

When you use dot notation, you are accessing the field, so in the examples you give, you are changing the values of the objects' `n` fields to the `Island` objects.

```
i2.n = i3; // The value of n inside i2 is now i3
i3.n = i4; // The value of n inside i3 is now i4
i4.n = i2; // The value of n inside i3 is now i2
```

This is a very basic element of any object-oriented programming language, so I suggest you read more about Java.

Comment: i know with dot I access another variable. I just dont know how i2.n works. Do I get access to Island n ?  If yes it looks like I can access Island n through i2,i3,i4 and this is where I am confused. Thanks for reply @SamTebbs33

Answer (score 1):

Because the member variable n of type Island that belongs to each instance of class Island is declared with the default scope (package private), you are able to directly access the field with the dot.

In other words, in this case yes you get access to Island n.